# How to Auto-Hide the address bar in Google Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, chrome-extensions

How can I hide the address bar in Google Chrome?  I found [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/93995/how-to-auto-hide-the-address-bar-in-google-chrome-and-chromium/) article but I am unable to find a solution for macOS.  Ideally, I would like all toolbars to disappear similar to how they do in QuickTime. see images:

[image: With tool bar showing]
[image: Hidden tool bar]

Is there such a solution available?

Comment: Btw, the article that you found is out of date.  Apparently Google did not like the way that experimental feature was turning out and disabled it.  :(  I have yet to find a way to do it either.

Comment: Did either of you find a way to solve this yet? I'm still using an ancient version of Chrome (~12.x), which is starting to break with all this new-fangled HTML5 stuff around.

Comment: @bassplayer7 will do, I have been neglecting the OSX stackexchange a bit.

Comment: Good. It benefits you and the answerer - the answerer not just with rep but also tags, I believe.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you want such a solution?

Comment: I love full screen mode apps, especally full-screen chrome not having to look at an address bar, however I don't like being limited to one app per window... eventually I would like to be able to navigate between my browser windows the same way I navigate between windows in vim, and I this as an effective way of accomplishing this.

Comment: @rudolph9: No worries, on the 0%. Thank you for taking the time to make sure. I appreciate the effort to keep SE a good resource.

Answer (score 147):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're asking, but I think you mean in full screen mode judging by the tags.

Simply uncheck **View > Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen** (<kbd>⇧⌘F</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: This does not answer my question, I looking for how to fill the entire content of a chrome window with html content without the necessity to be in full screen mode.

Comment: You should ask for clarification in a comment what a question is asking before answering if you are not sure.

Comment: @rudolph9 To be fair, there *was* a full screen tag.

Comment: So you can see how there might be a vague possibility I'd think you were talking about being in full screen mode.

Comment: So maybe some way to emulate fullscreen mode without actually going into fullscreen?

Comment: +1. While it did not answer OP's question, it did answer what I was looking for!

Answer (score 14):

As in other answers to this question, the best option I could find is by running chrome from a shell and passing in the --app (which runs google chrome in application mode or something of the sort) option as follows:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --app="http://www.google.com"
```

Answer (score 4):

go to `chrome://flags` and then search for `Immersive Fullscreen Toolbar` and set the value to `Enabled`, and that's it.

Or follow the following link to go directly to that setting.

```
chrome://flags/#enable-immersive-fullscreen-toolbar
```

Comment: Sadly, this option doesn't seem to exist in Chrome 96.0.4664.110.

Comment: I have been searching for the answer for a long time, but this is the one that actually works. I wonder why google does not add this into the menu options.

Answer (score 3):

To get full screen w/o address bar in Chrome on OSX use <kbd>Cmd-Shift-F</kbd>

Comment: This does not answer the question.  Please read more carefully.

Comment: Well, I found this answer useful when Googling this precise issue! Seems harsh to downvote it.

Comment: Lol just look through the menu items

Comment: Cmd-Shift-F is the key shortcut for the answer with the most votes: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/50797/65787

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable 100% the address bar in any browser anymore.

To do that, you need to recompile the sources of Chromium, Firefox etc. with the necessary changes.

This rule of mandatory address bar has been accepted because of scams and other critical issues caused by people that create fake evil things.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a windowed Chrome app with no menus the steps are as follows:

navigate to

```
chrome://flags
```

Enable the following two options:

1. "The new bookmark app system"
2. "Allow hosted apps to be opened in windows"

Restart Chrome to enable the options. Then navigate to the page you want to turn into an "app".

In the tools menu (three dots) click More Tools > Add to Applications

Finally, navigate to

```
chrome://apps
```

and right click on the icon for the newly added Application. Enable the "Open as window" option.

Answer (score 0):

I tried suggestion

0

go to chrome://flags and then search for Immersive Fullscreen Toolbar and set the value to Enabled, and that's it.

Or follow the following link to go directly to that setting.

chrome://flags/#enable-immersive-fullscreen-toolbar

but that flag doesnt exist my chrome says..

Comment: That must be answer with upvotes 0, not suggestion number 0. Please see [tour] for quick intro to the site. Also, if you have this question and none of the answers here work, ask a new question.